# Use ease-in-out with steps() in CSS

Tags: css, animation

I'm creating a loading spinner and having issues with the animation.

The sprite sheet runs through 22 steps. I'd like to use an easing effect at the start and end of the animation. When I add easing, the animation goes static.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Flignats/aaaaaf6h/3/

```
.hi {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64, ... ");

    -webkit-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
         -o-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
            animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1564px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1564px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1564px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1564px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1564px; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `steps` is one of the timing(*easing*) functions available (*and you cannot use multiple easing functions*).

Read the docs about [The steps() class of timing-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps%28%29_class_of_timing-functions)

> The `steps()` functional notation defines a step function dividing the domain of output values in **equidistant steps**.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If I remove the steps function and go with an ease timing, animation-timing-function: ease; the animation doesn't stay static. Any ideas on this?

Comment: The issue is that the easing controls the interpolation between the keyframes. Since you are animating the background-position the `x` gets animated with varying speeds (*based on the easing function*) and so it does not go to your predefined steps (*you see the background sprite at `x` positions where it does not fit in its container*). The only solution would be to use a linear easing function and manually create multiple keyframes that control the speed, but this will be hard to maintain or adjust.